# Django ModelChoiceField initial data not working for ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I am filling my form with initial data using the normail:

```
form = somethingForm(initial = {
                    'title' : something.title,                    
                    'category' : something.category_id,
                })
```

The title works fine, but if the category is a ModelChoiceField and a ForeignKey in the model, the initial data won't work.  Nothing will be selected in the Select Box.  If I change category to an IntegerField in the model it works fine.

I still want to use a ForeignKey for category though, so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try using an instance of a category rather than its ID?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
form = somethingForm(initial = {
                    'title' : something.title,                    
                    'category' : [("database value","display value")],
                })
```

### Why list of tuples?

1. Because choice fields are associated with select widget ( i.e
       html ===> 
       ..............)
2. For each option we need to specify two things 1.internal value
       2.display value (each tuple in the list specifies this)

Comment: I tried this and didn't work: 'category' : [(something.category_id,something.category_id.title)],

Comment: Also, this doesn't explain why if I change the model to an IntegerField without using the code you posted above it works fine.  Any ideas on why that is happening?